# Get Users/Shared Folder in Mac using C#

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, mono

Im trying to get the `Users/Shared` folder location in Mac so that i can write common user data(license) to it.I tried using

```
System.IO.Path.Combine (Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData));
```

But its returning the folder in which I'm logged in.I know that i need to place the common application data in the `Application Support` folder but i think root privilege is required for this.If there is a better way to write to that folder,please suggest.

UPDATE:

I tried doing

```
File.Copy ("myfile.rtf", "Users//Shared//ll.txt");
```

But i get this exception >> `Destination directory not found: Users/Shared`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `OS X` the directory is simply `/Users/Shared`, and it's directly off the root of the volume. There's no need to do `Environment.GetFolderPath...`

If you want to have user data or application data that can be shared by multiple users (read+write) you'll either want to create your own directory:

```
/Users/Shared/MyApp
```

and/or you can use:

```
/Users/Shared/Library/Application Support/MyApp
```

This way your application can share user data and application settings with all users. The `/Library/Application Support` folder (not to be confused with the one shared one), is owned by the system and anything that needs to write to it must obtain permission. The contents are read only, even for admin level users — something you'll want to consider when deciding where to store shared application data.

Comment: But what about catering for MacOS and iOS at the same time in the code?